# Change iPhone Simulator's window position on my MacBook Pro dual screen setup?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, macos, ios-simulator

iPhone Simulator is version 4.0 (211.1)

I know, this is a weird question for S.O., but I figured if anyone has seen this, it would be someone here.

I have a MacBook Pro with a 22" lcd attached. I run the 22" as my "main" screen with the dock and I use the MBP's display as a secondary.

I want the iPhone Simulator to run on the actual MBP's screen, so the first time I ran it and it popped up on the 22", I dragged it over to the MBP screen. But now, whenever I launch iPhone Simulator, while it does show up on the MBP screen, it's half way off the screen and I have to drag it up. Here's a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2iw7m2t/4

I tried removing the simulator's .plist, which put it back on my main screen as it should, but the same thing happens when I drag it back to where I want it.

I assume this is all due to running a 22" at 1920x1080 and the MBP 13" at 1280x800, but it doesn't change the fact that it's no bueno.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same problem.  I closed the simulator, ran rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist restarted the simulator and moved it to the position that I wanted.  Closed the simulator and the values of "NSWindow Frame iPhoneSimulatorWindow.0.0.500000" had changed.